# Procedure entry point could not be located in dll. How to fix Gstreamer dll issues?

Tags: c++, windows, dll, gstreamer

I have installed Gstreamer 1.0 1.22.10 from the official website(runtime then devel package). I'm able to link it to my project using Cmake, but if I run the .exe file of the code several pop-up windows appear with following messages

`The procedure entry point g_atomic_rc_box_acquire could not be located in the dynamic link library D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\bin\libgobject-2.0-0.dll`

`The procedure entry point g_atomic_rc_box_acquire could not be located in the dynamic link library D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\bin\libgstreamer-1.0-0.dll`

`The procedure entry point g_file_test could not be located in the dynamic link library D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\bin\libgmodule-2.0-0.dll`

I've seen several similar questions, but non of the solutions given to them were helpful in my case.
Also tried seeing if Dependency Walker would show anything, and it only confirmed, that, trule, these dlls don't have the specified enty points.

I feel like at this point there should be a precise algorithm to solve this issues with Gstreamer ddls, any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You're probably compiling or building the program in an invalid way, so you should say exactly what your build process is, how you installed everything, and include a [mcve].  Personally I'd recommend switching to a MinGW environment in MSYS2 and using its packages if possible.

Comment: It is a typical DLL Hell problem, the .h files you used when building the program don't match the .dll found at runtime.  For example, g_atomic_rc_box_acquire() appears to have been added in version 2.58, that doesn't sound much like version 2.0-0.